# How custom remote validation errormessage in mvc 5?

Tags: validation, model-view-controller

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Remote("CheckIdCard", "Lockers", ErrorMessage = "This Id Card have been used, Locker id is {0}{1}{2}")]
[MaxLength(18)]
public string IdCard { get;set;}
```

IF id Card have been exist in database, then client will show this record's id.

which method i should override ???

```
public class CustomErrMsgRemoteAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.RemoteAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return base.FormatErrorMessage(name);
    }
    //public override 
}

[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public JsonResult CheckIdCard(string IdCard)
    {
        bool isValidate = false;
        string val=string.empty;
        var locker = db.Lockers.Where(l => l.IdCard == IdCard).FirstOrDefault();
        if (locker==null)
        {
            isValidate = true;
        }
        else
        {
           string val=locker.Id;
        }
        // retrun this locker.id in errormessage;
        return Json(isValidate, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I don't know how to write these code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your metadata file or model class

```
[RemoteAttribute("IsRegionCodeExists", "Region",ErrorMessage="Region Code exists,  
public string RegionCode { get; set; }
```

NOW IN THE CONTROLLER

```
 //
    // GET: /Region/
    public JsonResult IsRegionCodeExists(string RegionCode)
    {
        return IsExist(RegionCode) ? Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) : Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public bool IsExist(string RegionCode)
    {
        var _model = (from s in db.Regions
                      where s.RegionCode == RegionCode
                      select s.RegionCode).FirstOrDefault();


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RegionCode)) return false;

        else if (_model!=null) 
             return false;
        else return true;
    }
```